# How to fix conda package installation error from intel-python-distribution environment in anaconda (windows)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, intel, conda

I'm trying to use python-intel-distribution for Anaconda in Windows 10. 
Intel Ref [Link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-distribution-for-python-with-anaconda).

The installation was successful using below command
`conda create -n idp intelpython3_full python=3`

But while I'm trying to use new packages(both intel or other), I'm getting below error -

*Collecting package metadata: failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch/repodata.json
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'conda.anaconda.org\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /intel/noarch/repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))*
[image: Error Screenshot]

Anyways, There is no such issue with conda base environment; all the packages getting installed in base environment.

Can anyone help me out with package installation in intel-distribution(idp) environment?

Comment: You seem to be missing SSL module. Install `openssl` as: `conda install -c anaconda openssl` or install it from its [website](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Comment: Got to know, it is open issue with conda. [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3292)